# Population of data structure by iterating over changelist -- only last update is present in output

Tags: python

I've spent most of the day pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.  I'm primarily a perl developer, so I'm struggling here in python.  I cannot figure out why only the last leaf of the tree and all the inner nodes have data, but all the other leaves are empty.

```
import json

data = [{'pos': '0-all.0', 'fld': 'labeled_element', 'ncmp': 'iexact', 'val': 'C'}, {'pos': '0-all.1', 'fld': 'labeled_element', 'ncmp': 'iexact', 'val': 'D'}, {'pos': '0-all.2-any.0', 'fld': 'labeled_element', 'ncmp': 'iexact', 'val': 'E'}, {'pos': '0-all.2-any.1', 'fld': 'labeled_element', 'ncmp': 'iexact', 'val': 'F'}]

def formsetToStructure(formset):
    qry = []
    for form in formset:
        curqry = qry

        # Get the path for this leaf
        path = form["pos"].split(".")

        # For each "edge"/"branch" of the path
        for spot in path:

            # inner nodes have a dash, e.g. "0-all" is the root inner node of type "all"
            pos_gtype = spot.split("-")
            if len(pos_gtype) == 2:
                pos = pos_gtype[0]
                gtype = pos_gtype[1]
            else:
                pos = spot
                gtype = None
            pos = int(pos)

            # Populate the node with a number of branches
            while len(curqry) <= pos:
                curqry.append({})

            # If this is an inner node, populate the inner node
            if gtype is not None:
                # This is a group
                curqry[pos]["pos"] = ""
                curqry[pos]["type"] = "group"
                curqry[pos]["val"] = gtype
                curqry[pos]["queryGroup"] = []
                curqry = curqry[pos]["queryGroup"]
                print("Setting pointer to",pos,"queryGroup")

            # Populate the leaf
            else:
                # This is a field
                print("Setting pos",pos,"type to field")
                curqry[pos]["type"] = "field"
                for key in form.keys():
                    if key == "pos":
                        curqry[pos]["pos"] = ""
                    elif key not in curqry:
                        print("Setting pos",pos,key,"to",form[key])
                        curqry[pos][key] = form[key]
                print()
    return qry

qry = formsetToStructure(data)
print(json.dumps(qry, indent=4))
```

I'm getting this out:

```
Setting pointer to 0 queryGroup
Setting pos 0 type to  field
Setting pos 0 fld to labeled_element
Setting pos 0 ncmp to iexact
Setting pos 0 val to C

Setting pointer to 0 queryGroup
Setting pos 1 type to  field
Setting pos 1 fld to labeled_element
Setting pos 1 ncmp to iexact
Setting pos 1 val to D

Setting pointer to 0 queryGroup
Setting pointer to 2 queryGroup
Setting pos 0 type to  field
Setting pos 0 fld to labeled_element
Setting pos 0 ncmp to iexact
Setting pos 0 val to E

Setting pointer to 0 queryGroup
Setting pointer to 2 queryGroup
Setting pos 1 type to  field
Setting pos 1 fld to labeled_element
Setting pos 1 ncmp to iexact
Setting pos 1 val to F
```

```json
[
    {
        "pos": "",
        "type": "group",
        "val": "all",
        "queryGroup": [
            {},
            {},
            {
                "pos": "",
                "type": "group",
                "val": "any",
                "queryGroup": [
                    {},
                    {
                        "type": "field",
                        "pos": "",
                        "fld": "labeled_element",
                        "ncmp": "iexact",
                        "val": "F"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the json output I expect to get:

```json
[
    {
        "pos": "",
        "type": "group",
        "val": "all",
        "queryGroup": [
            {
                "type": "field",
                "pos": "",
                "fld": "labeled_element",
                "ncmp": "iexact",
                "val": "C"
            },
            {
                "type": "field",
                "pos": "",
                "fld": "labeled_element",
                "ncmp": "iexact",
                "val": "D"
            },
            {
                "pos": "",
                "type": "group",
                "val": "any",
                "queryGroup": [
                    {
                        "type": "field",
                        "pos": "",
                        "fld": "labeled_element",
                        "ncmp": "iexact",
                        "val": "E"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "field",
                        "pos": "",
                        "fld": "labeled_element",
                        "ncmp": "iexact",
                        "val": "F"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Am I blind or am I fundamentally misunderstanding python in some way?

To give you an idea what this is doing / what it's for...  It is processing the input of this advanced search page:

[image: HTML page allowing data entry of nested query conditions]

Comment: What is you function even doing? Is recursion even necessary? Nothing seem nested.

Comment: you function is a bit long. can you consider split to several shorter functions, with meaningful names and parameters?

Comment: Whoops. My bad. It's not recursive.  The thing that constructed the input was recursive. I'll fix the title.

Comment: `input` is python reserved word. Try not to use it as variable name.

Comment: Yeah.  It's a bit long... Let be see if I can pretty it up with some comments and visual separations...

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I changed to input for this 'toy' example. I'll fix that too.

Comment: I added a gif to show what is generating the input to give you an idea what this is for, but for whatever reason, my edit with the gif isn't showing up...

Comment: The basic idea is that I'm passing in a list of dicts. Each dict has a "pos" key that defines that dict's location in a tree.  Inner nodes are a number and either "all" or "any" separated by a dash, e.g. "0-all".  The path is delimited with dots, so "0-all.2-any.1" is 2 inner nodes and a leaf `0->2->1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234181/discussion-between-hepcat72-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're starting from the root **and reinitializing your data structure** on every iteration, wiping out the data you'd previously filled in.

Change:

```
            if gtype is not None:
                curqry[pos]["pos"] = ""
                curqry[pos]["type"] = "group"
                curqry[pos]["val"] = gtype
                curqry[pos]["queryGroup"] = []
```

...to...

```
            if gtype is not None:
                if not curqry[pos]: # only initialize if empty
                    curqry[pos]["pos"] = ""
                    curqry[pos]["type"] = "group"
                    curqry[pos]["val"] = gtype
                    curqry[pos]["queryGroup"] = []
```

Comment: @hepcat72, ...the thing that helped me figure it out was adding a `print(qry)` to the loop, to log the state of the data structure as a whole as the program progressed. That said, this kind of need-another-pair-of-eyes situation is a place I've definitely been myself; glad to have been able to pay the favor forward. Good luck, and get some good rest! :)

Comment: OK.  I have the dynamic form working now.  Still have yet to construct and execute the query, but at least the dynamic form works.  I use the data from your fix to re-populate the form on page reload... https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qzCO5a3lFKl3M42KFqdfXGrH-v6zDE29